# XML Dynamic Serialization / Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I've got an object whose XML structure is dynamic and can change runtime based on the Application.

What I would like to do is specify the XML Element location for each property's declaration. However, it seems this can not be done in runtime and needs to be statically set. Is there another method for accomplishing what I would want to do?

```
 public class user
 {
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(XMLLocation.PersonUsername)]
      public String name;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean structure is dynamic? You have to define classes compile-time, don't you? Your attributes have to be compile-time constants, you can't do what you've proposed here and have the values varied runtime

Comment: You can create your intermediate data structure and use XSLTs to vary the output, I suspect you're trying to interface several different targets that have slightly different field names

Comment: Only the XML structure is dynamic. Not the class itself.

Comment: what does the XML structure depend on?

Comment: It varies, some of the XML structures are passed via other applications, the default is set by the application setting's file.

Comment: Perhaps you may have to roll your own by implementing IXmlSerializable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is the same but passed along to different applications I'd recommend using the same internal XML and processing it with XSLT before passing it along.

Implementing IXmlSerializable is certainly possible, so are other approaches, but you'll find yourself writing complex and unmaintainable code.

Comment: Isn't a dynamic xml unpredictable, and hence unmaintainable?

Comment: @Dhawalk the XML he needs is not "unpredictable", just several types of predetermined XML based on the same data. XSLTs would allow for add-ons without recompiling too.